# Twig template extract a subset

Tags: php, twig, template-engine

Is is possibile to extract a piece of a twig template?
I need to manage a table ajax refresh, I have a twig template for example:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<thead>
  <tr><th></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="mypiece">
  <tr><th></th></tr>
  <tr><th></th></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

In the first load I need the whole template, via ajax I need just the #mypiece content, is it possibile to extract it from twig using the DOM id or with some other markers?

The only solution I found is to divide this in two different template and use an include steatment.

**whole.html**

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th></th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="mypiece">
{% include 'content.html' %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**content.html**

```
  <tr><th></th></tr>
  <tr><th></th></tr>
```

But I think this is really a bad solution...

Answer (score 2):

Well, I personally prefer do actually divide them, but if you intend to get something with `AJAX` as well - try using embeded controllers (in this case, specifically for your `XHR` request), for example:

```
<tbody id="mypiece">
    {{ render(controller(
        'SomeBundle:SomeController:someAction',
        { 'someParameter': "something" }
    )) }}
</tbody>
```

This is a lot better then to parse some rendered template to get part of it, because to me it seems like design flow.

Even better solution is to return specified `json` data on ajax call and render it in one of the javascript template engines on the client side.

Hope this helps, cheers.